# define a matrix which does not know one dimension beforehand

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In one program, I need to create a `matrix`, which can be of shape, e.g,  `matrix.shape(x,100)`. The first dimension of shape cannot be known beforehand, so I just use `X` here. In an iteration, the program will generate one dimensional array such as 'Y.shape = (100,1)`.  So the program works as this

```
 matrix = []
 index = 0
 for i in range(XY):
    if something 
       matrix[index,:] = Y
       index = index+1
```

I am not sure whether I can initialize `matrix` this way, and do I need to reshape `Y` when I assign `matrix{index,:]=Y` in some iterations shown as above.

Comment: What is `XY`? Can you supply some working code with a small array?

Comment: Where is `i` used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a `numpy` array with an unknown dimension.  But despite the name, your `matrix` isn't an array, it's a python list:

```
In [1]: alist = []
In [2]: for i in range(3):
   ...:     alist.append(np.arange(4)[:,None])
   ...:     
In [3]: alist
Out[3]: 
[array([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3]]), array([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3]]), array([[0],
        [1],
        [2],
        [3]])]
In [4]: np.concatenate(alist, axis=1)
Out[4]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

You can efficiently append objects to a list.  Once filled that list can be converted into an array.  Here, because the elements are (n,1), I chose to concatenate to make a (4,3) array.  But `np.array`, `np.stack` or other axes could be used.

This basic idea of appending to a list, and making the array with one call after iteration is widely recommended.

`matrix[i,:] = Y` only works if `matrix` is large enough to start with.  It does not 'grow' matrix (contrary to MATLAB and Javascript practice).  You can concatenate one array to another iteratively, but that's less efficient.